# Is demanding backpayments of “arrears” after suspending access to subscription service an unfair contractual practice?

Tags: england-and-wales, european-union, consumer-protection, unfair-terms, consumer-rights-act-2015

A periodic (eg monthly) membership contract can have two ways of dealing with temporary nonpayment of fees.

Suppose Alice joins a members club for a 6 month contract and after the third month she has a financial lapse and becomes unable to pay her membership fees until the following month. After 5 days of her fourth monthly payment falling due, her access to the facilities was suspended.

A month later she finally gets paid and would like to restore access to the club so she goes to make payment and they claim that in order to reinstate her membership she needs to make up the last month’s worth of fees even though her service was suspended during most of the month in respect of which they are demanded. Alice would instead like to just pay for the month ahead and call it a day, presumably also commensurately extending her contractual commitment period of 6 months to exclude the delinquent month.

Is the club’s expectation in breach of unfair contract terms regulations and thus unenforceable? See in particular [example term 18 in part 1 of schedule 2 to the consumer rights act 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/schedule/2/paragraph/18/enacted).

Does the answer change if the service is rather for a website hosting service which temporarily disables the delinquent customer’s site?

In either case it seems like the situation would be different if they never suspended Alice’s access to the service/ facilities but instead maintained her access as contracted unconditionally while her civilly-recoverable liability for membership dues also continue to so unconditionally accrue. In this case, even if she didn’t use it, it would be more like rental arrears where liability accrues both for payments of fees and provisions of service for the whole contractually committed period. Ie, whether or not Alice has paid for April, her access is never revoked from January until June, but Alice’s liabilities continually accrue recoverable by the club in small claims court.

Comment: I think this has been answered before. They don't want subscribers to pay only when they dip into the resource. It is supposed to be a continual subscription whether or not the subscriber can afford to pay, or actually uses it. The postscript is a different question, and has a lot if 'ifs' for example if it wasn't available when the subscriber wasn't paying.

Comment: What they want or not seems irrelevant to the question of whether or not they can enforce their wishes on consumers: it seems like it would be different if they never suspended Alice’s access to the facilities. In this case, even if she didn’t use it, it would be more like rental arrears where liability accrues both for payments of fees and provisions of service for the whole temporal contractual term. Ie, whether or not Alice has paid for April, her access is never revoked from January until June, but Alice’s liabilities continually accrue recoverable by the club in small claims court.

Comment: They can enforce their wishes with "Terms & Conditions".

Comment: Alice's contention seems to be that because she's billed monthly, she's buying a monthly membership, but that's not the case at all. She bought a six-month minimum membership, she's just paying in installments. You might as well try buying a 12-pack of soda and sending two of them back for a refund.

Comment: @WeatherVane they can’t if they’re unenforceable.

Comment: @Cadence that’s not right, it would be more like if she paid for them in instalments and due to missing one of her payments they activated a remote switch that irreversibly ruins the contents of two of the cans, but still insist she make up the payment, which she is glad to do on the condition that she is supplied with two more cans of poop.

Answer (score 1):

### What does the contract say?

If it says they can, they can.

At common law, a contract term is unenforceable only if it’s unconscionable - that is, so onerous or one-sided that no one would ever agree to it. This isn’t even close to unconscionable.

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

Australia is unusual in that it makes *[unfair](https://www.accc.gov.au/about-us/publications/a-guide-to-the-unfair-contract-terms-law)* terms unenforceable under the Australian Consumer Law. However, terms that set the ‘upfront price’ are exempt - periodic payments are upfront if they are disclosed in the contract. However, even if it wasn’t it is not clear that suspending the service while in arrears causes “significant imbalance” between the parties - paying on time is something that is in the control of the consumer, not the supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some example terms that would allow the described scenario:

1. Alice will pay the Club $180 (the Total), in payments of $30 per month, made by the first day of each month starting January 2023 and ending June 2023 (the Period).
2. The Club will give Alice access to its facilities during the Period. But if Alice does not pay the Club $30 by the first day of a month during the Period (a Missed Payment), the Club may deny Alice access to its facilities until Alice pays the Missed Payment.
3. If the Club denies Alice access to its facilities due to a Missed Payment, Alice will continue to owe the Total for the Period.

---

<sup>This answer was written when the question was at [revision 3](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/96469/3). I will not be updating it to keep up with changing and expanding scenarios.</sup>

Comment: Nonetheless, would term #3 even be enforceable as a fair contract term?

Comment: It seems to me to fall foul of example term 18, pt. 1, sch. 2, Consumer Rights Act 2015, though in fairness you didn’t in any event specify any jurisdiction.

Comment: Hi @Jen, I’ve largely  rolled back the question to the revision that you addressed, however the point of my edits had actually been intended as to highlight that you made unfounded assumptions about the hypothetical scenario which doesn’t get as the crux of the question which had unwittingly been mainly about term 18, pt 1, sch. 2, CRA2015, which I edited back in to clarify.

Comment: is Alice not being retroactively made to fulfill her obligations in respect of an irretrievably past period for which the trader did not fulfill theirs?

Comment: which one? - - - - -

Comment: @Seekinganswers https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24153/the-sidebar

Comment: My feeling in retrospect is that this fundamentally betrays the basic thrust of the whole unfair contract terms regime, which is designed not to be contracted out of through legalese gymnastics and  creative drafting of terms. That’s why the provided unfair terms in the statutes are merely examples of terms which are likely to be unfair from which courts are simply to take inspiration when adjudging whether any given term is fair or unfair.

Comment: Thus while they do avoid using the exact pattern of example term 18 in part 1 of schedule 2, I would still not have great hope in their ability to hold up in court.